# Regex - how to validate non empty, not leading zero when decimals, max two decimals with or without decimal point(not comma)

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that there is many many answered questions 'bout this type of regex here on StackOverflow. Unfortunately I wasnt able to combine them properly to match my needs. So any help is apreciated:

I have a field, in which:
1. Any value between 0.1-99 should be entered
2. Only two digits separated or not by decimal point
3. The field must not be empty
4. There can not be white space or comma or any else character

Examples NOT OK:
01 or
0.0 or
 or
1,1 or
2.75 or
27.5 or
999 or
ab

Examples OK:
0.1 or
1 or
5.5 or
10 or
99

I hope it's clear. If not give examples and I will answer. Thank You!

Comment: What did you try and how did you fail?

Comment: Thanx to all who give me minuses to my question without any comment - this really helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, it's that easy in AngularJS!!! Just add a parameter "required" to field attributes and validation will fail if there is nothing filled in!

```
<input type="text" name="light1LowTimer_OnVal" class="form-control" ng-model="t.on.val" required ng-pattern="/^\d{1,2}(\.\d)?$/"/>
        <span ng-show="form.light1LowTimer_OnVal.$invalid && showInvalids" class="formError">Incorrect value</span>
```

Comment: Not that easy as I thought - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656230/angularjs-how-to-use-ng-required-only-for-active-fields

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression seems to work for your examples:

```
^(?:0\.[1-9]|[1-9]\.?\d?)$
```

It splits the task up into two approaches:

1. If the first digit is a `0`, there *must* be a decimal point and then a nonzero digit.
2. If the first digit is not a zero, there *may* be a decimal point and then there *may* be a digit.

If that one fails for you, please supply better examples.

See also [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/RlCwdW/1)

Comment: Tried this in https://www.regextester.com/ and there is 0 positive, without any next number or anything. This is wrong for me. There is necessary "If the first digit is a 0, there must be a decimal point and then a nonzero digit."

Comment: It seems that that website does not handle the anchors well. Remove them or replace them by `\b` for testing there.

Comment: Also, consider showing us the relevant Javascript code if your data does not match the regular expression.

Comment: OK, I'll try this at my code and let You know in approx 2 hours from now. Is there "The field must not be empty" implemented in this regex example?

Comment: `<div class="form-group" bs-has-error>
            <input type="text" name="light1LowTimer_OnVal" class="form-control" ng-model="t.on.val" ng-pattern="/^\d{1,2}(\.\d)?$/"/>
            <span ng-show="form.light1LowTimer_OnVal.$invalid && showInvalids" class="formError">Incorrect value</span>
        </div>`

Comment: regex "/^\d{1,2}(\.\d)?$/" allows to leave the field empty or allows to have leading zero without decimal point after it and this is what I' trying to solve.

Comment: regex from answer ^(?:0\.[1-9]|[1-9]\.?\d?)$ is partially OK, but allows the field leave completely empty.

Comment: I don't see how the regex can leave the field completely empty - either there must be a zero (case 1) or there must be a non-zero (case 2). Most likely the code you're using the regex in does not trigger. Maybe Angular always allows an empty or unchanged field?

Comment: "Angular always allows an empty or unchanged field?" - maybe..I'm not a programmer, I don't know. I was trying everything and when the field is empty, it does not trigger, as You say. SAD :-(

Comment: "If the first digit is not a zero, there may be a decimal point and then there may be a digit." -- is there a possibility to change it to: If the first digit is not a zero, there may be a decimal point and if there is a decimal point then there must be a digit and if not decimal point, then there may be a digit ? Because now it allows to put 1. (one digit and decimal point and nothing next) into the field and I don't want to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it. It's quite spaghetti code, but it seems to work:

`ng-pattern="/^(?:0\.[1-9]|[1-9]|[1-9]\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$/"`